# Can you edit vertices/faces on a text object?

Tags: modeling

Are text objects solid objects or made up of individual vertices and faces that you can edit? Can they be converted into an editable objects, maybe with the help of an add on? How about tracing it to make a new object?

Comment: Alt C is to hotkey for converting objects to curves or mesh. You will probably want a  mesh.

Answer (score 1):

It's made up of automatic tracing of a font. So it's its own type. 
To convert it into an editable object:

Select your text object.
Hit Alt + C and select to either convert it to a mesh or a curve.

Comment: It doesn't do anything in both object and edit mode. Does this also apply to 2.8?

Comment: I don't know. I use 2.79. Alternatives to the hotkey are spacebar > "convert" or, as you mentioned in your own solution Object > Convert to > ...

Comment: If you're on a mac and don't have `alt`, you can go `F3` to get the command search, then type in "convert" to get the same options

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer without using a hotkey.
In *Object Mode* go to menu Object > Convert To > Mesh from Curve/Mesh/Surf/Text.